# pause jQuery function for 5 seconds before script returns true and posts

Tags: php, jquery

Im using jQuery to post a form to a database, before posting the HTML form to a remote server via the form action method.

All works fine, but I am trying to build in a message pre-the server POST , so is there a way that just before my jQuery function returns true to get it to pause for 5 seconds and display a message?

```
    ...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myform.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $('#details').html("<div id='post-message'></div>");
            $('#post-message').html("<h2 style='color:#fff'>Thanks for getting in touch</h2>")
            //.append("<p>Thank you</p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                // $('#message').append("<img id='tick' src='images/tick.png' />");
            });
        }
    });
    return true; 
});
...
```

I ideally need a pause of 5 seconds just before the script returns true and finishes - any help much appreciated! Presently the message has no time to display as the script returns true and posts!

Thanks

Comment: Is there any problem in using setTimeout method.

Comment: There's no point of returning true here, this will run asynchronously and ALWAYS return true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout('func', 5000);` in the success function.

```
function doItLater()
{
    $('#details').html("<div id='post-message'></div>");
    $('#post-message').html("<h2 style='color:#fff'>Thanks for getting in touch</h2>")
    //.append("<p>Thank you</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
        // $('#message').append("<img id='tick' src='images/tick.png' />");
    });
}
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "myform.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        // do stuff now ...
        // wait 5 seconds
        window.setTimeout('doItLater', 5000);
        return true; 
    });
});
```

Comment: yes I was talking about pre. I made it more clear above in an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be sure that POST request is complete before doing some other things, try setting "async" param to "false" - see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/